# Trying to connect to Gmail's SMTP

Tags: email, smtp

I'm trying to connect to Gmail's SMTP.

First, I get its smtp server.

```
dig mx gmail.com
```

`gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com` is the one with the lowest priority.

I think I could try telnet'ing to that address at this point, however Gmail requires TLS, and telnet does not support it.

I try openssl then, for ports 25, 587 and 465:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:587
```

**The command above returns nothing... why?**

However, this one does connect:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server of gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com is not accessible on 587 port, but it is on 25.